# OPEN XML to Export 2007/2010

Tags: c#, export-to-excel, openxml-sdk

In my application I already have functionality to export into 2003 format. Where I am constructing a string out of the template and write using  System.IO.File.WriteAllText.

But it does not work with excel 2007/2010, that's why I wanted to convert it to Openxml in order to support 2007 and 2010.

I have string ready with creation of cells and rows from template.

I want advice on how to achieve or any body has reference link.

Please let me know.

Regards

Comment: Have you tried the Office Interop Excel API to create a workbook?

Comment: @Haris That solution is almost as worse as his current solution: slow, unmainnatable, random errors, and prone to hangs.
Use a library like EPPLUS, which can write native xlsx files in milliseconds and has a nice API, something which cannot be said of the native Office Open XML library

Answer (score 1):

WriteAllText class will save you a text file. You are saving an html(text) based file with xls extension. This is not a real xls file (that is actually a binary file), but MS Excel recognize and interpret the html format.

An xlsx file is a binary file. You can use OpenXML Office library ( Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook ) or another .NET Excel library like [EasyXLS](http://www.easyxls.com). Check [this sample of code](http://www.easyxls.com/manual/FAQ/export-to-excel-in-dot-net.html) for more details.

Comment: xlsx is not a binary, but  a compressed zip file. Can be handy if you have to debug xlsx files

Comment: It is indeed a zip file, but a zip file is also a binary file.